# same column calculation / percentage

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

How does someone in MYSQL compare a users percentage from a dates entry and score to another dates entry and score, effectively returning a users percentage increase from one date to another?

I have been trying to wrap my head around this question for a few days and am running out of ideas and feel my sql knowledge is limited. Not sure if I'm supposed to use a join or a subquery?  The MYSQL tables consist of 3 fields, name, score, and date.

TABLE: userData

```
name    score   date

joe      5      2014-01-01
bob     10      2014-01-01
joe     15      2014-01-08
bob     12      2014-01-08
```

returned query idea

```
user    %inc    last date

joe     33%     2014-01-08
bob     17%     2014-01-08
```

It seems like such a simple function a database would serve yet trying to understand this is out of my grasp?

Comment: What does %inc represent?

Comment: @OscarPérez: Seems it is *percentage increment*.

Comment: Yes, I know, but based on what? it is something like `last_value / previous value * 100.0`?

Comment: I don't understand the arithmetic

Comment: Whats the formula for getting column '%inc'

Comment: Can we rollback that edit :-(

Comment: Are you sure the output %inc you have given is correct???

Answer (score 0):

You need to use  `SUBQUERIES`. Something like:

```
  SELECT name,
         ((SELECT score
             FROM userData as u2
            WHERE u2.name = u1.name
         ORDER BY date desc
            LIMIT 1
          ) 
          /
          (
            SELECT score 
              FROM userData as u3
             WHERE u3.name = u1.name
          ORDER BY date desc
             LIMIT 1,1
          ) 
          * 100.0
         ) as inc_perc,
         max(date) as last_date
    FROM userData as u1
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution assuming that the formula for %Inc column = total/sum *100

```
select name,total/sum * 100, date from (
select name,sum(score) as total,count(*) as num,date from table group by name
)as resultTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.name as [user],(cast(cast(b.score as float)-a.score as float)/cast(a.score as float))*100 as '% Inc',b.[date] as lastdate 
from userdata a inner join userdata b on a.name = b.name and a.date < b.date
```

I guess you are looking for the % increse in the score compared to past date

Answer (score 0):

Another way (and note, that I have another result. Based on the name "percinc", percentage increase, I calculated it in my eyes correctly. If you want your result, just calculate it with `t1.score / t2.score * 100`):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`name` varchar(3), `score` int, `date` varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`name`, `score`, `date`)
VALUES
    ('joe', 5, '2014-01-01'),
    ('bob', 10, '2014-01-01'),
    ('joe', 15, '2014-01-08'),
    ('bob', 12, '2014-01-08')
;
```

Query:

```
select
t1.name,
t1.score first_score,
t1.date first_date,
t2.score last_score,
t2.date last_date,
t2.score / t1.score * 100 percinc
from
t t1
join t t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where
t1.date = (select min(date) from t where t.name = t1.name)
and t2.date = (select max(date) from t where t.name = t1.name);
```

Result:

```
| NAME | FIRST_SCORE | FIRST_DATE | LAST_SCORE |  LAST_DATE | PERCINC |
|------|-------------|------------|------------|------------|---------|
|  joe |           5 | 2014-01-01 |         15 | 2014-01-08 |     300 |
|  bob |          10 | 2014-01-01 |         12 | 2014-01-08 |     120 |
```

- [<kbd>**live demo**</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/683904/3/0)

Comment: `t2.score-t1.score / t1.score * 100 percinc` is the correct formula